# How to import xlrd into Google Cloud Datalab

Tags: google-cloud-platform, jupyter, google-cloud-datalab

I am trying to import some data from an Excel spreadsheet into Jupyter on Google Cloud Datalab:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import xlrd
import re
plt.style.use('ggplot')
```

I get the following error:

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-9a99b78364cd> in <module>()
      2 import numpy as np
      3 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
----> 4 import xlrd
      5 import re
      6 plt.style.use('ggplot')

ImportError: No module named xlrd
```

I understand that I have to install the xlrd module. How can I get this done or request for this to be done on Datalab?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run either of the following in a cell within a datalab notebook:

```
!pip install xlrd
```

or

```
%%bash
pip install xlrd
```